# ¿Como colocar los cuadros uno al lado del otro?

Tags: php, css

como puedo colocar los cuadros uno al lado del otro, quiero formar 3 filas luego abajo 3 mas y por ultimo las 2 ultimo pero al crear los cuadros aparecen uno abajo del otro. Busque varias formas de como poner uno al lado del otro pero ninguno me daba resultado, estuve tratando con los css quitando cosas agregando cosas pero nada me daba resultado, proporciono una parte del código el resto es todo igual a lo que ya estoy agregando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
        <div class="row vertical-gap">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="nk-feature-1">
                    <div class="nk-feature-icon">
                        <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nk-feature-cont">
                        <h6>Licencia AntiCheat UAC Version 2.6</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="nk-feature-1">
                    <div class="nk-feature-icon">
                        <img src="img/icon-mouse.png" alt>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nk-feature-cont">
                        <h6>FastDownload Gratis</h6>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor revisa [ask] , saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo con **display flex**, debes considerar que los elementos a alinear dependerá mucho de su contenedor padre, al asignar la alineación es como se alinearan los hijos, ya sea en columnas o filas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso el elemento padre es el **body**, sus hijos los div con clase **class="row vertical-gap"** así sucesivamente. Te dejo un ejemplo con el CSS comentado para que lo comprendas mejor.

```css
body {
  /*contenedor padre*/
  /*utilizamos display flex*/
  display: flex;
  /*al contenedor padre le damos la direccion en columnas a los hijos en row filas*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*centramos elemntos en X*/
  align-items: center;
  /*asignamos altura al cuerpo de la pagina body*/
  height: 400px;
  /*asignamos el ancho*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.text-main-1 {
  color: orange !important;
}

h6 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nk-gap,
.nk-gap-1,
.nk-gap-2,
.nk-gap-3,
.nk-gap-4,
.nk-gap-5,
.nk-gap-6 {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
}

.row {
  /*UTILIZAMOS DISPLAY FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  /*ALINEAMOS LOS CONTENEDORES HIJOS EN FILAS*/
  flex-direction: row;
  /*EL TAMAÑO DE ANCHO DEL CONTENDOR AL 100*/
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row.vertical-gap {
  margin-top: -30px;
  /*AGREGUE UN MARGEN PARA SEPARAR LOS DIV DE LA BASE*/
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.row.vertical-gap>[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.col,
.col-1,
.col-10,
.col-11,
.col-12,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
.col-5,
.col-6,
.col-7,
.col-8,
.col-9,
.col-auto,
.col-lg,
.col-lg-1,
.col-lg-10,
.col-lg-11,
.col-lg-12,
.col-lg-2,
.col-lg-3,
.col-lg-4,
.col-lg-5,
.col-lg-6,
.col-lg-7,
.col-lg-8,
.col-lg-9,
.col-lg-auto,
.col-md,
.col-md-1,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-md-auto,
.col-sm,
.col-sm-1,
.col-sm-10,
.col-sm-11,
.col-sm-12,
.col-sm-2,
.col-sm-3,
.col-sm-4,
.col-sm-5,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-7,
.col-sm-8,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-auto,
.col-xl,
.col-xl-1,
.col-xl-10,
.col-xl-11,
.col-xl-12,
.col-xl-2,
.col-xl-3,
.col-xl-4,
.col-xl-5,
.col-xl-6,
.col-xl-7,
.col-xl-8,
.col-xl-9,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nk-feature-1,
.nk-feature-2,
.nk-feature-3,
.nk-feature-4,
.nk-feature-5,
.nk-feature-6,
.nk-feature-7,
.nk-feature-8 {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /*ASIGNAMOS DISPLAY FLEX*/
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*ESTE CONTENEDOR HIJO LE DAMOS EL 90% DEL TOTAL DEL CONTENEDOR PADRE*/
  width: 90%;
  /*ASIGNAMOS UNA ALTURA PAREJA A TODOS LOS CONTENDORES PARA QUE TENGAN EL MISMO TAMAÑO*/
  height: 90px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #232930;
  border: 1px solid #293139;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nk-feature-1 .nk-feature-cont,
.nk-feature-2 .nk-feature-cont {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 38px;
}

.nk-feature-1 .nk-feature-icon,
.nk-feature-2 .nk-feature-icon {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 29%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #293139;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Contenedor Padre-->
  <!--subcontenedor 1-->
  <div class="row vertical-gap">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>Licencia AntiCheat UAC Version 2.6</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>FastDownload Gratis</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>Otro</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--subcontenedor 2-->
  <div class="row vertical-gap">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>Licencia AntiCheat UAC Version 2.7</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>FastDownload Gratis 2</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="nk-feature-1">
        <div class="nk-feature-icon">
          <img src="img/anticheat2.png" width="45" height="45">
        </div>
        <div class="nk-feature-cont">
          <h6>Otro 2</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Nota:** Obsérvalo en tu navegador, si te sirvió la respuesta acéptala o puntuala con la flechita hacia arriba de la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Estos son los estilos que uso

```css
.text-main-1 {
    color: orange !important;
}
h6 {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.nk-gap, .nk-gap-1, .nk-gap-2, .nk-gap-3, .nk-gap-4, .nk-gap-5, .nk-gap-6 {
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.row.vertical-gap {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.row.vertical-gap>[class*=col-] {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.nk-feature-1, .nk-feature-2, .nk-feature-3, .nk-feature-4, .nk-feature-5, .nk-feature-6, .nk-feature-7, .nk-feature-8 {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 44%;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #232930;
    border: 1px solid #293139;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.nk-feature-1 .nk-feature-cont, .nk-feature-2 .nk-feature-cont {
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 38px;
}
.nk-feature-1 .nk-feature-icon, .nk-feature-2 .nk-feature-icon {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #293139;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```